# Resize the elements when mouse over

Tags: jquery, html, css

I borrowed a piece of code from web for self learning purpose.It works well, please see it at [jsfiddle demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/zhshqzyc/PvxY2/)

I want to add some dynamic effects such as when mouse hover the dot, the dot size will be doubled.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.grilldots').mouseover()(function(){
       $(this).resize(function(){
          $('.grilldots').height()=52;
          })
     });
 });
```

The above code is not working.

The original dot's size is 26 in CSS.

```
.grilldots{
    line-height:0%;
    height:26px;
    width:260px;
    letter-spacing: -0.075em;
    color:#be2f08;
    font-size:8em;
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #fd6e4d;
 }
```

Further, I want to make the eye sort of flashing when mouse hover it, which could be changing color something like.

Comment: The fiddle isn't working ? Should there be any effect on hovering? If that's the case, it isn't being processed.

Comment: Why not using CSS's `hover` effect? or I misunderstood the concept in the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok first of all you had two problems.. the first was because you are assigning the event the wrong way and the second because you assign the height the wrong way as well.

```
$(seletor).on('event_name', function() {
});
```

And

```
$(selector).height(value);
```

Now I've modified your fiddle to make an effect:
[The modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PvxY2/7/)

Although I prefer moving this stuff to CSS and benefit from its :hover selector.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the right way to assign height
$('.grilldots').height()=52;

It should be:
$('.grilldots').height(52);

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the value in the wrong way and you are using the `mouseover` function in a wrong way. Change it in and it will do something(I think it is not the effect that you expected)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.grilldots').mouseover( function(){
    $(this).height(52);
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PvxY2/2/

I also saw that you had errors in your JS. You can easily check this by hitting the `F12` key and check your console :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay - So adding this to your CSS works.

```
.grilldots:hover {height: 52px!important;}
```

But I don't think it's giving you your desired effect, as it doesn't work when you directly hover the dots individually.  Which tells me they need to be styled differently altogether.

**http://jsfiddle.net/PvxY2/6/** - Hover up and down between the eyes.

*Note - The important isn't necessary*

Answer (score 0):

`$.resize` is supposed to be an event listener for when something gets resized. It's not meant to resize the element.

You should be using:

```
$('.grilldots').mouseover(function(){
   $(this).height(52);
});
```

Not sure if this is the effect you were looking for, however.